# Por que el metodo Arrays.Sort no funciona?

Tags: java

Arrays.Sort no funciona de esta manera

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SegundaClase miClase=new SegundaClase();
    Arrays.sort(miClase.Elint());

    for (int i = 0; i <miClase.Elint().length; i++) {

        System.out.println(miClase.Elint()[i]);
```

Segunda Clase:

```
public class SegundaClase{

int []a=new int[5];
public int[] Elint(){
    a[0]=122;
    a[1]=23;
    a[2]=42;
    a[3]=251;
    a[4]=125;
    return a;
```

Pero si funciona de esta manera:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SegundaClase miClase=new SegundaClase();
    int []aR= miClase.Elint();
    Arrays.sort(aR);
    for (int i = 0; i <aR.length; i++) {

        System.out.println(aR[i]);
    }
}
```

A que se debe?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El método anda perfecto. El problema es que no estas mostrando lo que ordenaste

Vos haces lo siguiente:

```
SegundaClase miClase=new SegundaClase();
Arrays.sort(miClase.Elint());
```

y eso ordena el array devuelto.. pero para mostrarlo haces lo siguiente:

```
for (int i = 0; i <miClase.Elint().length; i++) {
    System.out.println(miClase.Elint()[i]); <- problema!!!
```

cada vez que haces `miClase.Elint()[i]` estas llamando de vuelta a la función

```
public int[] Elint(){
    a[0]=122;
    a[1]=23;
    a[2]=42;
    a[3]=251;
    a[4]=125;
    return a;
```

Y esa función, vuelve a reescribir el array, desordenado.. Por lo tanto tu problema viene en querer llamar a esa función y pensar que esta ordenado, cuando la misma función lo reescribe cada vez que la llamas.

Mejor, tener un `get` que reciba la posición y devuelva el elemento de a que vos querés ;)